# python Pandas DataFrame copy(deep=False) vs copy(deep=True) vs '='

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, deep-copy

Could somebody explain to me a difference between

```
df2 = df1

df2 = df1.copy()

df3 = df1.copy(deep=False)
```

I have tried all options and did as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5])
df2 = df1
df3 = df1.copy()
df4 = df1.copy(deep=False)
df1 = pd.DataFrame([9,9,9])
```

and returned as follows:

```
df1: [9,9,9]
df2: [1,2,3,4,5]
df3: [1,2,3,4,5]
df4: [1,2,3,4,5]
```

So, I observe no difference in the output between `.copy()` and `.copy(deep=False)`. Why?

I would expect one of the options '=', copy(), copy(deep=False) to return `[9,9,9]`

What am I missing please?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you see the object IDs of the various DataFrames you create, you can clearly see what is happening.

When you write `df2 = df1`, you are creating a variable named `df2`, and binding it with an object with id `4541269200`. When you write `df1 = pd.DataFrame([9,9,9])`, you are creating a *new* object with id `4541271120` and binding it to variable `df1`, but the object with id `4541269200` which was previously bound to `df1` continues to live. If there were no variables bound to that object, it will get garbage collected by Python.

```
In[33]: import pandas as pd
In[34]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5])
In[35]: id(df1)
Out[35]: 4541269200

In[36]: df2 = df1
In[37]: id(df2)
Out[37]: 4541269200  # Same id as df1

In[38]: df3 = df1.copy()
In[39]: id(df3)
Out[39]: 4541269584  # New object, new id.

In[40]: df4 = df1.copy(deep=False)
In[41]: id(df4)
Out[41]: 4541269072  # New object, new id.

In[42]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([9, 9, 9])
In[43]: id(df1)
Out[43]: 4541271120  # New object created and bound to name 'df1'.

In[44]: id(df2)
Out[44]: 4541269200  # Old object's id not impacted.
```

Edit: Added on 7/30/2018

Deep copying [doesn't work in pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17406) and the devs consider putting mutable objects inside a DataFrame as an antipattern. Consider the following:

```
In[10]: arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
In[11]: arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
In[12]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[arr1], [arr2]], columns=['A'])
In[13]: df1.applymap(id)
Out[13]: 
            A
0  4515714832
1  4515734952

In[14]: df2 = df1.copy(deep=True)
In[15]: df2.applymap(id)
Out[15]: 
            A
0  4515714832
1  4515734952

In[16]: df2.loc[0, 'A'].append(55)
In[17]: df2
Out[17]: 
               A
0  [1, 2, 3, 55]
1   [1, 2, 3, 4]
In[18]: df1
Out[18]: 
               A
0  [1, 2, 3, 55]
1   [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`df2`, if it was a true deep copy should have had new ids for the lists contained within it. As a result, when you modify a list inside df2, it affects the list inside df1 as well, because they are the same objects.

Comment: Hi! But what is the difference between df1.copy() and df1.copy(deep=False) ? Can you improve example to show this difference?

Comment: This is helpful, since I now see that the difference between `df2 = df1` and `df2 = df1.copy(deep=False)`; one creates a new object with a new id.  But I still don't understand why that matters?  They are still both just references to `df1`, right? They will still get garbage collected the same way, right?  Or, does the shallow copy actually create a new container object, except that all of the elements are in fact pointing to the same reference?  If so, that seems like the worst of all worlds:  consumes most of the memory (millions of duplicated pointers) but still don't have a true copy.

Comment: @karolszk: I've added an example to illustrate how deep copying doesn't work in pandas as you would expect it to.

Comment: If someone is looking for a good example I have made an attempt here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578453/python-pandas-df-copy-ist-not-deep/61582117#61582117

Answer (score 6):

Deep copy creates new id's of every object it contains while normal copy only copies the elements from the parent and creates a new id for a variable to which it is copied to.

The reason for none of `df2`, `df3` and `df4` displaying `[9,9,9]` is:

```
In[33]: import pandas as pd
In[34]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5])
In[35]: id(df1)
Out[35]: 4541269200

In[36]: df2 = df1
In[37]: id(df2)
Out[37]: 4541269200  # Same id as df1

In[38]: df3 = df1.copy()
In[39]: id(df3)
Out[39]: 4541269584  # New object, new id.

In[40]: df4 = df1.copy(deep=False)
In[41]: id(df4)
Out[41]: 4541269072  # New object, new id.

In[42]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([9, 9, 9])
In[43]: id(df1)
Out[43]: 4541271120  # New object created and bound to name 'df1'.
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to modify df's elements individually. Try the following

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5])
df2 = df1
df3 = df1.copy()
df4 = df1.copy(deep=False)

df1.iloc[0,0] = 6
df2.iloc[1,0] = 7
df4.iloc[2,0] = 8

print(df1)
print(df2)
print(df3)
print(df4)

df1:        df2:        df3:        df4:
   0           0           0           0
0  6        0  6        0  1        0  6
1  7        1  7        1  2        1  7
2  8        2  8        2  3        2  8
3  4        3  4        3  4        3  4
4  5        4  5        4  5        4  5
```

Comment: Edited to show the results, this is really the best way to see what's going on.  In the original question the re-assignment of `df1` doesn't really illustrate the real issue of copying, this example does.  `df3`, using `.copy()` is the only deep copy of the 3 options.