# Purpose of pandas DataFrame.copy(deep=False)?

Tags: python, pandas

What is the purpose of pandas'

```
>>> df2 = df.copy(deep=False)
```

? (`df` is a pandas DataFrame.)

---

Isn't that the **exact** same thing as

```
>>> df2 = df
```

?

If there is a difference, please explain.  If there is no difference, why bother allowing for the `deep` flag?  Why not remove the flag parameter, since we're all comfortable knowing the 'shallow copy via assignment' from the rest of Python?  Or maybe call the method `deepcopy` instead of `copy`, to make the fact that it is a deep copy explicit.

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46329399/7120232). Hope it helps.

Comment: There are subtlety vs. related questions regarding the meaning. Note that `dataframe` contains `data entries` and `indexes`. They are indicated by `reference` to memory location (like pointer in C), let's call `df_ref`, `data_ref`, `ind_ref`, respectively. In `df2 = df`, `df_ref` is assigned to df2. The use case is to simply have 2 `vars` pointing to the same dataframe. In `df2 = df.copy(deep=False)`, `df2` gets a new `df2_ref` but contains the old `data_ref` and `ind_ref`. The use case is to share a copy of possibly large `data` while avoiding accidentally modifying due to shared `df_ref`.

Comment: @THN Thanks!!  Now that helps to clarify things!  (The question that @coldspeed @Abhishek Arya pointed to did not really help for me.)  It's the knowledge that the `ind_ref` and `data_ref` are still referring to the original `dataframe` while `df2_ref` is new that was key.  :)  Follow up, when using `df.copy(deef=True)`, can I assume that **nothing at all** is shared?

Comment: Yes, the intention of `deep=True` is to copy to the lowest level, so you can assume that, if pandas implements it correctly.