# Python pandas df.copy() ist not deep

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, deep-copy

I have (in my opinion) a strange problem with python pandas. If I do:

```
cc1 = cc.copy(deep=True)
```

for the dataframe cc and than ask a certain row and column:

```
print(cc1.loc['myindex']['data'] is cc.loc['myindex']['data'])
```

I get

```
True
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: What is `cc1.loc['myindex']['data']`? An integer, a string, something mutable?

Comment: What is the result of `cc.loc['myindex']['data']` and `cc1.loc['myindex']['data']`? They should be the same, as you made a copy of `cc`, or not?

Comment: it is a dict ... I thought 'is' compares objects but not contents?

Comment: A dict is a Python object and pandas does not copy them recursively. See the note in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html): "When deep=True, data is copied but actual Python objects will not be copied recursively, only the reference to the object. This is in contrast to copy.deepcopy in the Standard Library, which recursively copies object data (see examples below)."

Comment: so copy.deepcopy can be applied to dataframe?

Comment: This code really needs to show what `cc` is to begin with.  Also, it's not clear why you think something is wrong, best to explain what you would expect and why you would expect it.

Answer (score 1):

Deep copying doesn't work in pandas and the devs consider putting mutable objects inside a DataFrame as an antipattern

There is nothing wrong in your code, just in case if you want to know the difference with some example of deep and shallow copy() here it is.

## Deep copy

```
dict_1= {'Column A': ['House','Animal', 'car'],
     'Column B': ["walls,doors,rooms", "Legs,nose,eyes", "tires,engine" ]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_1, columns=['Column A', 'Column B'])

# Deep copy
df2 = df1.copy()  #  deep=True by default
df2 == df1  # it returns True because no updates has happened on either of dfs
output
#   Column A    Column B
# 0 True    True
# 1 True    True
# 2 True    True

id(df1)  # output: 2302063108040
id(df2)  # ouptut: 2302063137224
```

Now if you update Column B of `df1`

```
dict_new =  {'Column A': ['House','Animal', 'car'],
     'Column B': ["walls", "Legs,nose,eyes,tail", "tires,engine,bonnet" ]}

# updating only column B values
df1.update(dict_new)

df1 == df2   # it returns false for the values which got changed
```

output:

```
    Column A    Column B
0   True    False
1   True    False
2   True    False
```

And if we see df1 # which is deeply copied it remains unchanged

```
df1
# output:
# Column A  Column B
# 0 House   walls,doors,rooms
# 1 Animal  Legs,nose,eyes
# 2 car tires,engine
```

## Shallow copy

```
df2 = df1.copy(deep=False)  #  deep=True by default hence explicitly providing argument to False
df2 == df1  # it returns True because no updates has happened on either of dfs
# output
#   Column A    Column B
# 0 True    True
# 1 True    True
# 2 True    True

dict_new =  {'Column A': ['House','Animal', 'car'],
     'Column B': ["walls", "Legs,nose,eyes,tail", "tires,engine,bonnet" ]}

df1.update(dict_new)

df2 == df1  # since it has same reference of d1 you will see all true even after updating column B unlike deep copy
# output
#   Column A    Column B
# 0 True    True
# 1 True    True
# 2 True    True

df2  # now if you see df2 it has all those updated values of df1

# output:
#   Column A    Column B
# 0 House   walls
# 1 Animal  Legs,nose,eyes,tail
# 2 car tires,engine,bonnet
```

Source: 
[python Pandas DataFrame copy(deep=False) vs copy(deep=True) vs '='](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327494/python-pandas-dataframe-copydeep-false-vs-copydeep-true-vs)
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html

Answer (score 0):

To create a deepcopy of a dictionary, the following code should work:

```
import copy
dict1 = {'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 7}
dict2 = copy.deepcopy(dict1)
for i in dict1:
    dict1[i] += 5
print(dict1)
print(dict2)

{'a': 10, 'b': 11, 'c': 12}
{'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 7}
```