# Deepcopy Pandas dataframe with all python objects inside of it, including lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, deep-copy

When running the code below it would seem deepcopy does not deep copy the list inside the df.
How is possible to deepcopy a dataframe df in such a way that no modification can come back to the original df ?

```
from copy import deepcopy
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'molecule': ['a','b','c','d','e'], 'species' : [['dog'],['horse','pig'],['cat', 'dog'], ['cat','horse','pig'], ['chicken','pig']]})
tmp = deepcopy(df)

df.loc[2]['species'].remove('dog')

|    | molecule   | species                 |
|---:|:-----------|:------------------------|
|  0 | a          | ['dog']                 |
|  1 | b          | ['horse', 'pig']        |
|  2 | c          | ['cat']                 |
|  3 | d          | ['cat', 'horse', 'pig'] |
|  4 | e          | ['chicken', 'pig']      |
```

Is there something I can do so that 'cat' remains present in the tmp dataframe?

Comment: I tried to insert the table outside the code block but stack overflow would not let me :(

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578453/python-pandas-df-copy-ist-not-deep. From the top answer: *"Deep copying doesn't work in pandas and the devs consider putting mutable objects inside a DataFrame as an antipattern"*. In your case, you could consider using tuples instead of lists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pandas df.copy() ist not deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578453/python-pandas-df-copy-ist-not-deep)