# Change a copy of a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I wrote the following **Python** script:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("homeprices.csv")
# df heve no column 'm'

M = df
M['m'] = ['a', 'b' , 'c','a', 'b' , 'c','a', 'd' , 'c','d', 'b' , 'c' ,'c']

df
```

But now `df` **have** a column `'m'`!!

**Why?!!!**

Comment: ``id(M)`` & ``id(df)`` you will see both pointing to same reference, ``M`` is shallow copy ``df``.

Comment: Here is a dupe, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46329399/4985099

Comment: please refer to ```copy()``` documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Answer (score 1):

That's because you used `M = df` and now the `M` is equal to `df`. IF you will make any changes to the `M`, also the `df` will receive them. It might be tricky, but that's how it works. Also if you would delete any record from the `df` it would be also deleted from the `M`