# Python Pandas Using functions of a DataFrame 'function' object has no attribute 'dtypes'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror

#### Context:

I am working with dataBases and dataFrames, so i need to get some version of the dataFrame that i am extracting and transforming, so i decided to use `.copy` function to get independents DataFrames. I am using **Jupyter Notebook**.

#### Show an reproducible example

I am doing something similar than this example.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame from Dictionary
technologies = {
    'Courses':["Spark","PySpark","Hadoop"],
    'Fee' :[20000,25000,26000],
    'Duration':['30day','40days','35days'],
    'Discount':[1000,2300,1500]
              }

raw = pd.DataFrame(technologies)

#Copy the dataFrame to have a BackUP

df = raw.copy

print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<bound method NDFrame.copy of    Courses    Fee Duration  Discount
0    Spark  20000    30day      1000
1  PySpark  25000   40days      2300
2   Hadoop  26000   35days      1500>
```

Until this point everything seems well. But when i execute some function for that dataFrame, like dtypes to get all types of the elements of the dataframe.

`df.dtypes`

**OUPUT:**

`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'dtypes'`

Comment: You are not copying your `raw` dataframe in `df.= raw.copy`. You are _assigning_ the method `copy` of the dataframe to the variable `df`, and then you're trying to call `.dtypes` on it. Do `df = raw.copy()` (notice the `()`) to actually **call** the method `copy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataFrame.copy is a method that returns a deep copy of the dataFrame by default (you can set deep=False to get a reference to the same dataFrame).

```
df = raw.copy()
df.dtypes
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thx for the answer! About your extra explanation of `deep=false` if you use it, you have to care about what you do with the dataframe because if you change it, it will change the main dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

It is unnecessary to use the copy function here.

You can simply assign your new data frame to be the raw data frame and you will have a copy of both. For example

```
df = raw
```

This will not alter the raw dataset and you can alter df as you would like. No information will be lost.

Full Example:

```
import pandas as pd
technologies = {
'Courses':["Spark","PySpark","Hadoop"],
'Fee' :[20000,25000,26000],
'Duration':['30day','40days','35days'],
'Discount':[1000,2300,1500]
          }

 raw = pd.DataFrame(technologies)

 df= raw

 print(df.dtypes)
 df.head()
```

Running this will show we maintained the structure and data in raw and copied raw into df

Comment: The point is that if you use `df = raw` you will change the dataset of raw also, won´t you?

Comment: As i told you i checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327494/python-pandas-dataframe-copydeep-false-vs-copydeep-true-vs), when you declare a new dataframe and set with the dataframe before it will bind it with the other dataframe